# In Postgres: Select columns from a set of arrays of columns and check a condition on all of them

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, loops

I have a table like this:

[image: Table]

I want to perform count on different set of columns (all subsets where there is at least one element from X and one element from Y). How can I do that in Postgres?

For example, I may have {x1,x2,y3}, {x4,y1,y2,y3},etc. I want to count number of "id"s having 1 in each set. So for the first set:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE x1=1 AND x2=1 AND x3=1;
```

and for the second set does the same:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE x4=1 AND y1=1 AND y2=1 AND y3=1;
```

Is it possible to write a loop that goes over all these sets and query the table accordingly? The array will have more than 10000 sets, so it cannot be done manually.

Comment: what do you mean by "go over all these sets"? Do you say that you need all permutations  of sets containing x1-y4 ?

Comment: Correct! For all possible combinations of X and Y (order is not important of course). The actual table has more than 8 columns. So the number of permutations is even higher. I can alternatively do this in Python if there is a solution for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able convert the table columns to an array using `ARRAY[col1, col2,...]`, then use the [`array_positions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html) function, setting the second parameter to be the value you're checking for. So, given your example above, this query:

```
SELECT id, array_positions(array[x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4], 1)
FROM tbl
ORDER BY id;
```

Will yield this result:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id |  array_positions  |
+----+-------------------+
|  a |  {1,4,5}          |
|  b |  {1,2,4,7}        |
|  c |  {1,2,3,4,6,7,8}  |
+----+-------------------+
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d620e/1).

Comment: The postgres version I am using doesn't support "array_positions" function (is 9.2).But your answer helped find a solution in python! :-) Thanks.